# How do I make my Entity Framework based Repository Class LINQ friendly?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern

How can I use LINQ if I have wrapped my Entity Framework data context with a Repository class?

I want to do something like:

```
class A 
{
   public IRepositiry<T> GetRepository<T>()
   {
       DbContextAdapter adapter = new DbContextAdapter(ctx);
       return new Repository<T>(adapter);
   }
}

class B
{
   void DoSomething()
   {
      A a = new A();
      IRepository<House> rep = a.GetRepository<House>();

      // Do some linq queries here, don't know how.
      rep.[get Linqu] (from ...);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you are the only person that knows what `rep.[get Linqu] (from ...);` means.

Comment: There is so much missing info here. What's `ctx`? What methods does `IRepositiry<T>` define? What is `Repository<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

To keep your repository LINQ friendly you need to have some methods or properties on it that return `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`

So in class `Repository<T>` you would have a method like this:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
   DbContextAdapter ctx;

   // other methods omitted

   IEnumerable<Houses> GetHouses()
   {
       return ctx.Houses
   }
}
```

Then in `DoSomething` you could do this:

```
void DoSomething()
{
  A a = new A();     
  IRepository<House> rep = a.GetRepository<House>();     

  var q = from house in rep.GetHouses()
          where house.Color = "Purple"
          select house;

  foreach(var h in q)
  {
    house.SetOnFire();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is your repository class a generic collection ? It provides no benefit as far as I can see.

Comment: I just worked from the example provided by the original poster.  My goal was to make it as close to his example as possible so the answer will be easier for him to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> The standard query operators allow queries to be applied to any
>   IEnumerable-based information source. - MSDN

As long as you write methods that return IEnumerable Collections you will be compatible with LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

at the risk of been completely lazy, what you want to implement is known as the repository pattern, check out [Huyrya](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/) as its a good article.

Also it's possible to extend the entity classes, so they return instances or lists of themselves (singleton pattern). Aka:

```
public partial class FOO : FOO
{
      public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFooList()
      {
           using (var context = new FooEntities())
           {
               return // YOU CODE TO GET LIST OF FOO
           }
       }
}
```

Or something like that (code syntax is not right but should give you the general idea). If your entity classes are going to implement similar methods, abstract them into interface contract and get your partial entity classes to implement that interface.